# Prevent background rebuidling when calling emit()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, custom-painter

I have a background that is drawn using Flutter custom painter and it uses the Random() function to draw shapes at random positions (ex.: stars), also I have a widget that has a timer, this timer ticks every second and every second I use emit() inside my cubit to update my screen.

My problem is when the screen gets updated every second, the background also gets updated with new positions for my shapes, and every second nearly two rebuilds which means that my background rebuilds itself two times for every second (that's a disaster for the Memory), besides this background must be static, so how to prevent this unnecessary rebuilds?

my stack widget which holds the timer and background behind it:
my backgrounds are NightClipper(), LightClipper() and DayTimeline() widgets they are being rebuilt although they're not included in my BlocConsumer()

```
      Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        ClipPath(
          clipper: NightClipper(
            portrait: _portrait,
            lightRegionFraction: light,
            nightRegionFraction: night,
          ),
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: DayNightView(
              portrait: _portrait,
              lightRegionFraction: light,
              nightRegionFraction: night,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ClipPath(
          clipper: LightClipper(
            portrait: _portrait,
            lightRegionFraction: light,
            nightRegionFraction: night,
          ),
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: DayLightView(
              portrait: _portrait,
              lightRegionFraction: light,
              nightRegionFraction: night,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        CustomPaint(
          painter: DayTimeline(
            portrait: _portrait,
            fajrFraction: light,
            sunriseFraction: 0.2,
            dhuhrFraction: 0.45,
            asrFraction: 0.6,
            maghribFraction: night,
            ishaFraction: 0.8,
          ),
        ),
        BlocConsumer<HomeScreenMainWidgetCubit, HomeScreenMainWidget>(
          listener: (context, value) {
            context.read<HomeScreenMainWidgetCubit>().refresh();
          },
          builder: (context, value) {
            return Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                CustomPaint(
                  foregroundPainter: NextPrayerIndicator(
                    indicator: value.indicatorValue,
                    portrait: _portrait,
                  ),
                  painter: Background(
                    portrait: _portrait,
                  ),
                ),
                CustomPaint(
                  painter: CountdownTimer(
                    timer: value.nextPrayerTimer,
                    portrait: _portrait,
                  ),
                ),
                CustomPaint(
                  painter: PrayerTitle(
                    title: value.nextPrayerTitle,
                    portrait: _portrait,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
```

My provider code

```
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => HomeScreenMainWidgetCubit()..init(),
        ),
```

My cubit code

```
class HomeScreenMainWidgetCubit extends Cubit<HomeScreenMainWidget> {
  HomeScreenMainWidgetCubit()
      : super(HomeScreenMainWidget(
          indicatorValue: 0.0,
          nextPrayerTitle: '...',
          nextPrayerTimer: Duration(
            hours: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0,
          ),
        ));

  /*
  0 -> sunrise
  1 -> sunset / maghrib
  2 -> fajr
  3 -> dhuhr
  4 -> asr
  5 -> isha
   */

  Timer? _timer;
  List<Duration>? _prayerTimes;

  void init() {
    bool gps = SharedPreferencesService.getGPSBool() ?? false;
    if (gps == true) {
      Position? position = SharedPreferencesService.getPosition();
      _prayerTimes = PrayerTimes.getAuto(
        position!,
        DateTime.now(),
      );
    } else {
      String country = SharedPreferencesService.getCountry() ?? 'Egypt';
      String state = SharedPreferencesService.getState() ?? 'Cairo';
      _prayerTimes = PrayerTimes.getManual(
        country,
        state,
        DateTime.now(),
      );
    }
    refresh();
  }

  void refresh() {
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      emit(HomeScreenMainWidget(
        indicatorValue: NextPrayer.getIndicatorValue(
          _prayerTimes!,
          DateTime.now(),
        ),
        nextPrayerTitle: NextPrayer.getTitle(
          _prayerTimes!,
          DateTime.now(),
        ),
        nextPrayerTimer: NextPrayer.getTimer(
          _prayerTimes!,
          DateTime.now(),
        ),
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Note that in my custom painter, my shouldRepaint function returns false, so I don't know why my background gets updated on each emit.

edits:
here's my stateless widget

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static String id = 'home_screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    bool isPortrait = !((size.width > kPhoneMaximumScreenWidth) ||
        (orientation == Orientation.landscape));
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => HomeScreenMainWidgetCubit()..init(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          isPortrait
              ? Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      // flex: 5,
                      child: Semantics(
                        // todo build semantics
                        child: ClipRect(
                          clipper: BackgroundClipper(
                            portrait: isPortrait,
                          ),
                          child: HomeScreenStackDesign(
                            portrait: isPortrait,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      // flex: 2,
                      child: Semantics(
                        // todo build semantics
                        child: ClipRect(
                          clipper: BackgroundClipper(
                            portrait: isPortrait,
                          ),
                          child: HomeScreenStackDesign(
                            portrait: isPortrait,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Your build() might get called 60 times per second.  It should be idempotent and fast.  If you have random items, they should be stored in State, and recomputed only at chosen times.

Comment: okay, I'm listening can you please explain this more? @RandalSchwartz

Comment: What part is unclear?

Comment: how to store it in State? what do u mean by that? kindly explain it more @RandalSchwartz

Comment: I'm using stateless widget and its buid() returns my provider as top level in my tree and btw when I converted to Stateful widget I have the same problem, my background keeps updating with each emit() and note that I'm using a Random() function inside my Paint() method inside custom painter with for-loop which loops 100 times to draw 100 shapes at different positions of the screen

Comment: check out my edits in the question above please @RandalSchwartz

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable like this:

```
Widget backgroundWidget;
```

and fill it in `initState` like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    backgroundWidget = Stack(
      children:[
         ClipPath(
          clipper: NightClipper(
            portrait: _portrait,
            lightRegionFraction: light,
            nightRegionFraction: night,
          ),
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: DayNightView(
              portrait: _portrait,
              lightRegionFraction: light,
              nightRegionFraction: night,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ClipPath(
          clipper: LightClipper(
            portrait: _portrait,
            lightRegionFraction: light,
            nightRegionFraction: night,
          ),
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: DayLightView(
              portrait: _portrait,
              lightRegionFraction: light,
              nightRegionFraction: night,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        CustomPaint(
          painter: DayTimeline(
            portrait: _portrait,
            fajrFraction: light,
            sunriseFraction: 0.2,
            dhuhrFraction: 0.45,
            asrFraction: 0.6,
            maghribFraction: night,
            ishaFraction: 0.8,
          ),
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
```

and pass this `backgroundWidget` to your main stack widget:

```
Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        backgroundWidget,
        BlocConsumer<HomeScreenMainWidgetCubit, HomeScreenMainWidget>(
          listener: (context, value) {
            context.read<HomeScreenMainWidgetCubit>().refresh();
          },
          builder: (context, value) {
            return Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                CustomPaint(
                  foregroundPainter: NextPrayerIndicator(
                    indicator: value.indicatorValue,
                    portrait: _portrait,
                  ),
                  painter: Background(
                    portrait: _portrait,
                  ),
                ),
                CustomPaint(
                  painter: CountdownTimer(
                    timer: value.nextPrayerTimer,
                    portrait: _portrait,
                  ),
                ),
                CustomPaint(
                  painter: PrayerTitle(
                    title: value.nextPrayerTitle,
                    portrait: _portrait,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
```

in this way your `backgroundWidget` always paint once and not change in rebuild.

Comment: Doesn't this helpful to you? @saifkandil